# If $m\left( \sum_{k=1}^n E_k \right)>n-1 $ and each $m(E_k)>0,$ is it true that $m\left( \bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right)$ has positive measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Statement** $1$: Let $E_1,...,E_n$ be measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ such that 
>   $$m\left( \sum_{k=1}^n E_k \right) >n-1.$$
>   is it true that $m\left( \bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right)$ has positive measure?

The answer to the above statement is no, as 
$$E_1=E_2 = C$$
where $C$ is the Cantor Middle-Third set in $[0,1]$ serves as a counterexample. 
Indeed, 
$$E_1+E_2 = C+C = [0,2]$$
has measure $2>1$ but $C$ has measure $0.$

However, by imposing condition that each $E_k$ has positive measure, will the modified statement hold.
In particular,

> **Question**: Let $E_1,...,E_n$ be measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ such that 
>   $$m\left( \sum_{k=1}^n E_k \right)>n-1 \quad \text{and} \quad m(E_k)>0 \text{ for each } 1\leq k\leq n.$$
>   Is it true that $m\left( \bigcap_{k=1}^n E_k \right)$ has positive measure?

For the question, I could not come up with a counterexample to disprove it as the cantor set does not work here.

However, I also could not provide a proof to show the question is true.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Just make $E_i=(1-\epsilon)C\cup U_i$ where the $U_i$ are disjoint tiny open sets near $1$

Comment: I've never seen anyone use $\sum$ and $\cap$ at the same time for set operations. Maybe $\sum$ and $\prod$. Maybe $\cup$ and $\cap$. But never mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1\le k\le n$, let
$$ A_k=k\sqrt 2+\Bbb Q,$$
let $$A=\bigcup_k A_k $$
and finally
$$E_k=\left(\left[\tfrac {k-1}n,\tfrac {k}n\right)\setminus A\right)\;\cup\; \bigl([0,1]\cap A_k \bigr)$$
Then the $E_k$ have measure $\frac 1n$, are even *pairwise* disjoint, but $\sum E_k$ differs from $[0,n]$ by only countably many points.